In Golang Templ project how to us vite generated index.html
I have golang templ project. For the base layout I want to use the generated page from vite.
Here is how the generated index.html looks:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + TS</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-C4TiYRgV.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-C357VLdR.css">
  </head>
  <body class="bg-slate-150 text-yellow-600">
    {{ define "content" }}{{ end }}
  </body>
</html>


I want to use vite so that I can add packages and have little bit of ts sanity. I also want to use tailwind here is the config:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "../internal/templates/*.templ"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

Is there a way to say?
 templ.ReadFile...
I looked at the integration with html/template but couldn't figure a way to use it.

I managed to load the html using http/template and make it into templ. Now I need to know how to use other templ components inside...
goTemplate,err := template.New("index.html").Funcs(template.FuncMap{}).ParseFiles("./fe/dist/index.html")
and then
templ Index() {
@templ.FromGoHTML(loadTmepl(), "")
}

I made it work using http/templ like this:

    goTemplate,err := template.New("index.html").Funcs(template.FuncMap{}).ParseFiles("./fe/dist/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        panic(err)
    }
    var sb = strings.Builder{}
    page.Render(ctx,&sb)
    return goTemplate, template.HTML(sb.String())


Added a suggestion to add ParseFile or something like it to templ: https://github.com/a-h/templ/issues/795
